# Problem configuring swagger with aspnetboilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, aspnetboilerplate

We have a Netcore application with aspnetboilerplate and swagger. We want to change the swagger URL. For this we use:

```
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>     
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample API");
                options.RoutePrefix = "sdAPi/swagger";
            }
        );
```

The problem is that we also want to use the abp UI. For that we use:

```
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => 
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample API");                
            options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream("SmartDoc.Web.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
        });
```

These two lines give conflict. If we don't put RoutePrefix , swagger starts at the default URL, with the UI characteristics of swagger and abp.

If we use only RoutePrefix, swagger loads well into the URL.

As soon as we put RoutePrefix and IndexStream, swagger does not load the services.

```
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => 
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample API");
            options.RoutePrefix = "sdAPi/swagger";
            options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream("SmartDoc.Web.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
        });
```

Swashbuckle: 2.3.0.0
Abp: 3.8.1
Netcore: 2.1

---

How can I use both properties?, or... How can I change the default swagger address without using RoutePrefix?

Greetings

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @aaron swagger does not load the services, Only shows the header, and the rest of the page is empty: http://i66.tinypic.com/ib9kl3.jpg

Comment: No repro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww4nM.png. Check your browser console.

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't load the abp js, because I was looking for them on another route. We have modified the paths to the js from index.html, and it already works. Thank you